# Module not found error in AngularJS unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying a very simple test with Karma/Jasmine, to unit test my AngularJS app. This seems to work

```
beforeEach(
        module('myApp')
);

it('should blah', function () {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

while this doesnt

```
beforeEach(
    function () {
        module('myApp')
    }
);

it('should blah', function () {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

I want to be able to do other stuff beforeEach test suite, but it's not giving me any meaningful errors to be able to debug it, the only one I see is

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'currentSpec.queue.running')
```

relating to the line where the function is called within the beforeEach construct in the second example.

Im hoping someone else has come across this and can assist?

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: I imagine that calling `module(..)` returns something meaningful and `function(){ module(..); }` return this function (as an argument to `beforeEach( arg )`) Even calling that function doesnt `return` anything.

Comment: Can't you call beforeEach several times, can you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats just how you declare your module.  If you want to do more you can just use an additional beforeEach.

For Example:

```
var scope;
var ctrl;
var mysvcMock;

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(function() {
    mysvcMock = {

    };
});

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('MyController', {
        $scope: scope,
        mysvc: mysvcMock
    });
}));

//it checks
```

Let me know if you need more clarity on this and I can put together a fiddle for you.

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: Thanks Jordan, that helped!

Comment: I would need more clarity Jordan because I do not understand your solution but I have the same error as @stephenmc just look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480873/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-currentspec-queue-running It would be nice if you could help :)