# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'currentSpec.queue.running')

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am using karma + jasmine.

Now thatI have tried one way of mocking a dependent factory I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'currentSpec.queue.running')
at C:/test/test/client/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1924
at C:/test/test/client/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1979
at C:/test/test/client/test/spec/services/lessonplannerfactory.js:31
at C:/test/test/client/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:117
at C:/test/test/client/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171
at http://localhost:3000/karma.js:189
at http://localhost:3000/context.html:85


// load the service's module
beforeEach(module('clientApp'));

var lessonPlannerFactory;
var data;

beforeEach(inject(function (_lessonPlannerFactory_, _dailyPeriodsTestDataFactory_) {  // The underscores before/after the factory are removed by the $injector
    lessonPlannerFactory = _lessonPlannerFactory_;
    data = _dailyPeriodsTestDataFactory_;

}));

beforeEach(function(){
    // Arrange
    var dateFactory = {
        getVisibleDateRange: function (startDate, endDate, visibleWeekDays) {
            // I do not care about the parameters, I just want to stub out the visible days with 2 stubs
            return [
                moment(new Date(2014,0,1)),
                moment(new Date(2014,0,2))
            ];
        }
    };

    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('dateFactory', dateFactory);
    });
});

it('creates periods by daily rotation and a given timetable', function() {

    // Act
    var periods = lessonPlannerFactory.createPeriodsDaily(data.startDate, data.endDate, data.visibleDays, data.rotation, data.timetableEntries);

    // Assert

});
```

// LessonplannerFactory

```
angular.module('clientApp').factory('lessonPlannerFactory',['dateFactory', function (dateFactory) { // inject the dateFactory into this factory

    function createPeriodsDaily(startDate, endDate, visibleDays, weeklyRotation, timeTableEntries) {

        var visibleDateRange = dateFactory.getVisibleDateRange(startDate,endDate, visibleDays);

        // todo: Implement the whole algorythm
        var query = visibleDateRange;
        return query;
    }

    return {
        createPeriodsDaily: createPeriodsDaily

    };
}]);
```

// DateFactory

```
angular.module('clientApp').factory('dateFactory', function () {

    /// Computes all visible days with a given start date and end date (timespan)
    // startDate: momentJS object
    // endDate: momentJS object
    // visibleWeekDays: integer array of day index of a week
    function getVisibleDateRange(startDate, endDate, visibleWeekDays) {
        var visibleDateRange = [];

        // todo: Implement the algorythm

        return visibleDateRange;
    }

    return {
        getVisibleDateRange: getVisibleDateRange
    };
});
```

The lessonplannerFactory uses the dateFactory so I have to mock it for a real unit test.

When this code is run in debugging:

```
module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('dateFactory', dateFactory);
        });
```

Then the debugging stops because somewhere in the code happens the error posted at the top.

I know this link: [Module not found error in AngularJS unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410823/issue-with-jasmine-testing-on-angularjs-module-not-found)

It has my error message, but I do not understand the solution to adapt it to my scenario.

Anyone can help please?

Comment: come up with a specific test case where you have a specific issue. I dont see any issue here , just asking for a recommendation. what is your problem? there is no problem here.You have jasmine bundled with karma , then use it.

Comment: @mpm I will do so later!

Comment: NOW I updated my post with  my problem :)

Comment: @mpm Any advise from you? Now that I have posted a problem here :)

Comment: I got this exact error when upgrading to Jasmine 2.1. I fixed it (it fixed itself) by upgrading angular and angular-mocks to 1.2.16.

Answer (score 1):

I only have a few minutes right now but I think one of your issues here is that you are trying to test much more than a unit.  Unit testing is very specific and simplistic in its purpose.  When I do it I try to inject as little as possible and minimize dependencies.  In your case, instead of having one test suite for this I think you should have a suite for each one.  Try something more like this:

```
describe('DateFactory unit tests', function() {    
    beforeEach(module('clientApp'));


    describe("when getting a visible date range", function() {
        beforeEach(inject(function(dateFactory) {
            spyOn(dateFactory, 'getVisibleDateRange').andReturn(2013);
        }));

        it('should be 2013', inject(function(dateFactory) {
            expect(dateFactory.getVisibleDateRange(param1, param2, param3)).toBe(2013);
        }));
    });
});

describe('LessonPlannerFactory unit tests', function() {
    var data, lessonPlannerFactory;

    beforeEach(module('clientApp'));

    describe('When creating daily periods', function() {
        var query = "your visible date range";

        beforeEach(inject(function(lessonPlannerFactory) {
            spyOn(lessonPlannerFactory, 'createPeriodsDaily').andReturn(query);
        }));

        it('Should be the visible date range', inject(function(lessonPlannerFactory) {
            expect(lessonPlannerFactory.getVisibleDateRange()).toBe(query);
        }));
    });
});
```

I hope that helps out a bit.

Jordan

Comment: Thanks for your help. If would be great from you if you would still have some minutes. I understand your code BUT when I test the lessonplannerFactory that is is a real unit test I have to stub out the dateFactory and create a stub object else the result of the lessonplannerfactory.createPeriodsDaily depends on a wrong implementation of the dateFactory.getvisibleDateRange. I want to avoid that. Can you show me please how to mock a dependency like dateFactory - if you want use spyOn - from a unit test with the lessonplannerFactory.createPeriodsDaily() ? :)

Comment: Should this: expect(lessonPlannerFactory.getVisibleDateRange()).toBe(query); not be this: expect(lessonPlannerFactory.createPeriodsDaily()).toBe(query); ? :)

Comment: Ok the problem was a total different one: return [
                moment(new Date(2014,0,1)),
                moment(new Date(2014,0,2))
            ]; That way I can not return an array. Instead I pushed the 2 moment date objects to the array and it worked fine!

Comment: Did you use the pattern I showed above?  I would still recommend testing the services in an isolated sense.  Then you can use E2E tests for the bigger picture.

Comment: Thats odd when I use the wrong array declaration NOW again it works. Seems some other changes made it work :/. I know your pattern. Its an integration test. I prefer unit tests with mocking in that business logic core unit. But yes I also do integration testing (E2E) :)

Answer (score 0):

This one solves my issue:

try to change isSpecRunning function on angular-mocks.js

```
function isSpecRunning() {
    return currentSpec && currentSpec.queue && currentSpec.queue.running
        || currentSpec; // for Mocha.
}
```